# Emacs proper cl-flet indentation?

Tags: emacs, elisp

The current indentation for `cl-flet` seems really ugly to me.
See for instance:

```
(defun foo (lst)
  (cl-flet ((unusually-long-bar (x)
                                (1+ x)
                                (1+ x)
                                (1+ x)))
    (mapcar #'unusually-long-bar lst)))
```

I'd like to set it to something more sensible, like:

```
(defun foo (lst)
  (cl-flet ((unusually-long-bar (x)
              (1+ x)
              (1+ x)
              (1+ x)))
    (mapcar #'unusually-long-bar lst)))
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `cl-flet` has a `(declare (indent 1) ...)` form in it. This is what decides how the macro is indented. I don't think there's an easy patch, but just so you know, you can use a function reference in place of `1`, and that function will be called with the forms it has to indent, but I'm not sure about the exact things it should return.

Comment: Why not simply break all arguments to the function `unusually-long-bar`, instead if wrapping some and others not? Now it looks like the `(x)` was significantly different from the other arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following should work:

```
(setq lisp-indent-function 'common-lisp-indent-function)
(eval-after-load "cl-indent"
  '(progn

    (put 'cl-flet 'common-lisp-indent-function 
     (get 'flet 'common-lisp-indent-function))

    ))
```

Comment: This works for `cl-flet`, but now my `if` statements are misindented:
both `then` and `else` clauses are now at same level.

Comment: This is the standard way to indent `if` in common lisp. If it bothers you, add `(put 'if 'common-lisp-indent-function 2)`

Comment: Thanks, it works. But only when I eval it. I tried to put it it `~/.emacs`, in `emacs-lisp-mode-hook`,in `eval-after-load` - doesn't work.

Comment: You don't need to wrap `setq`. You need to put all `put`s inside `(eval-after-load "cl-indent")

Comment: I'd recommend against `(setq lisp-indent-function #'common-lisp-indent-function)`. You'll find that many Elisp forms are no longer indented properly.

Answer (score 3):

By way of addition to Sabof's answer, here is a snippet which copies indentation rules from all Common Lisp symbols to their `cl-` prefixed Emacs equivalents, when the latter exist:

```
(load-library "cl-indent") ; defines the common-lisp-indent-function properties
(cl-loop for symbol being the symbols
         for cl-indent-rule = (get symbol 'common-lisp-indent-function)
         for elisp-equivalent = (intern-soft (concat "cl-" (symbol-name symbol)))
         when (and cl-indent-rule elisp-equivalent (fboundp elisp-equivalent))
         do (put elisp-equivalent 'common-lisp-indent-function cl-indent-rule))
```

Comment: I think the only thing missing here is `(setq lisp-indent-function 'common-lisp-indent-function)`.